# Escape html by PHP then add by jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html-entities

I have following html (html may be vary) in php variable. I have used append function (jQuery) for adding this html but always fail...... (due to not properly formated html). I've tried htmlentities,html_entity_decode and htmlspecialchars function for formating html but not success.... :( Any-buddy know how to escaped this html. (either by PHP or jquery and how???? appreciate for your answer)

```
<tr>
    <td class='paramlist_key'>
        <label id='ID' for='FOR' class='CLASS'>*AT</label>
    </td>
    <td class='CLASS_A'>
        <select id="19" name="Name" class="cc" title="" style="" size="">
            <option value="" >Select below</option>
            <option value="A" selected="selected">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
        </select>
        <span id="mm" style="display:none;">&nbsp;</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: $('elementIdentification').before("<?php echo $html; ?>");

Comment: "due to not properly formated html" what error you are getting?

Comment: I was just going to edit it by [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)

Comment: look here maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery

Comment: Have you tried to use only `"` or `'` in your html? I see you're using both and that would most likely break the js.

Comment: You have some HTML code in a PHP variable and you're asking how to append that in jQuery. Is your actual question: How can I append the response of an AJAX request by jQuery? I'm confused.

Comment: @ManishTrivedi what is `elementIdentification` the problem seems to be with the jQuery selector

Comment: @tftd: Html generate by dynamically ...... (get from API)

Comment: @inhan: It's not ajaxified. Just added in jquery and task(add and remove html) as per action (Java-script event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the HTML to a valid JavaScript string, which means it has to be 1 line and all "-quotes or '-quotes must be escaped, depending on which your outer style will be in the final JS. So something like:

```
$html = str_replace("\n", "\\n", $html);
$html = str_replace('"', '\"', $html);
```

Or even easier, just `json_encode()` it and omit the quotes in the JS script itself as `json_encode()` will add those.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript code execution may be broken because of next line.
Try this:

```
$('elementIdentification').before("< ?php echo str_replace('\r\n','',str_replace('\n','',$html)); ?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not require jQuery Append to do this, if the HTML is decoded, you may simply echo it.

Comment: he may be getting the html via ajax

Comment: This html add and remove as per action (java-script events)

Comment: Ok, then my answer is useless, I will be deleting it in a while